# Trace of polynomials/algebraic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

I am somewhat stuck with the proof of Lemma 2.3 on page 6 in [this paper about an algorithm for polynomial factorization](https://www.math.fsu.edu/~hoeij/knapsack/paper/knapsack.pdf).

The preliminaries:

We have

- $f \in Z[X]$ monic, squarefree (which here means no multiple roots) with degree $N$
- A prime number $p$ such that $f \mod p$ remains squarefree (not sure if this is important here)
- $f = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$

We also define (for a field $F$ and some $i \in \mathbb{N}$) the $i$-trace of a polynomial $g \in F[X]$ as
$$
Tr_i(g) := \sum_{l=1}^{\deg(g)} \zeta_l^i
$$
where the $\zeta_l$ are the $\deg(g)$ (not necessarily different) roots of $g$, as well as, for an integer $l$
$$
Tr_{1\dots l}(g):=\left(Tr_1(g),\,\dots,Tr_l(g)\right)
$$
Since $Tr_i(gh) = Tr_i(g) + Tr_i(h)$, all these terms can also be defined more generally for $g \in F(X)$ if we put
$$Tr_i(q/r) = Tr_i(q) - Tr_i(R)$$.

Now, to the problem I'm facing:

> Assume we have, for indices
>   $v_1,\,\dots,v_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ that $$ g = \prod_i f_i^{v_i} \in
> \mathbb{Q_p}(X)  $$ Let $\alpha_1,\,\dots, \alpha_N$ be the roots of
>   $f$ in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. We can put $$
>  V_i:=Tr_{1,\,\dots,N}(f_i) \in \mathbb{Q_p}^N $$ and $$
>  V:=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i V_i = Tr_{1\dots N} (g) =
> \left(Tr_1(g),\,\dots,Tr_N(g)\right) $$ How do we show that $$ V \in \mathbb{Q}^N \implies V \in \mathbb{Z}^N $$ holds?

The author says that this follows due to the roots of $f$ being 'algebraic integers'.
I've only found that apparently, $a$ being an algebraic integer as well as a rational number implies it's an integer.
But I don't see how that would apply to the $Tr_i(g)$.

I've also never worked with algebraic integers before. I found their definition as the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{C}$, but we're in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q_p}$, (how?) can we just ignore that? Or are we really only working in the splitting field of $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X] \subset \mathbb{Q}[X]$?

What I have found, but which didn't seem to help me/probably is useless:

- The roots of $f$ are $p$-adic integers, hence so are the $Tr_i(g)$ (use the uniqueness of $p$-adic expansions and that $f$ is monic), but that only means their denominators are not divisible by $p$...
- Trivially, if $V \in \mathbb{Q}^N$, then if $b_1,\,\dots,b_\nu$ are the roots of $g$ counted with multiplicity, $\left(b_1,\,\dots,b_\nu\right)$ fulfills multiple algebraic relations with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, given by the components of $V$.

Comment: The algebraic integers $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}$ is the set of algebraic numbers whose minimal polynomial is in $\Bbb{Z}[X]_{monic}$, equivanelty such that $\Bbb{Z}[a]$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}$-module, from the latter $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}$ is a ring, thus $f \in \Bbb{Z}[X]_{monic}$ implies its roots and traces are in $\overline{\Bbb{Z}}$, and since they are also rational numbers they are in $\overline{\Bbb{Z}} \cap \Bbb{Q} = \Bbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\mathbb Q_p$ vs $\mathbb C$ problem doesn't really matter for various reasons, one of them being that (as abstract fields) $\mathbb Q_p$ sits inside $\mathbb C$, therefore so does one algebraic closure.

You could also argue as you do : what matters is the splitting field of $f$ and this is unique up to isomorphism, and those isomorphisms cannot move $\mathbb{Z,Q}$ so any result concerning those doesn't depend on which splitting field you choose.

Algebraic integers in a field $B$ containing $\mathbb Z$ are precisely the roots of monic integer-coefficient polynomials.

The proof that an algebraic integer that is also rational is an integer is independent of the field $B$, it's actually quite easy.

Now this applies to $Tr_i(f)$ because $f$ is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, therefore its roots are algebraic integers, and it can be shown (this is more subtle) that algebraic integers in $B$ form a subring of $B$, that means they are stable under addition and multiplication : if $x,y$ are algebraic integers, so are $xy$ and $x+y$.

You can easily deduce from that that if $\zeta_1,...,\zeta_r$ are algebraic integers, so is $\sum_j \zeta_j^i$: this is your $Tr_i(f)$.

Comment: Ah I vaguely remember that I at some point went over the fact that they form a ring. That's what was missing, thank you. How does $\mathbb{Q}_p$ sit inside $C$? I didn't find anything googling "abstract field".

Comment: "abstract field" is not an actual mathematical term, it's just there to say "field", as opposed to "field with an absolute value" (which both $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Q_p$ have, and so if I said that $\mathbb Q_p$ embedded in $\mathbb C$ it might have implicitly meant "as valued fields" - saying "as abstract fields" explicitly forbids that interpreation; you will find similar expressions when dealing e.g. with topological groups : if you say "isomorphic as abstract groups" you mean "explicitly leaving the topology out of the question")

Comment: As for why $\mathbb Q_p$ sits inside $\mathbb C$ it is either simple or complicated depending on your background : the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$ is a characteristic $0$ algebraically closed field of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (the same as $\mathbb C$) and therefore it is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. An "easy" way to see at least why it embeds in $\mathbb C$ is to pick out a transcendance basis, compute its size, embed that in $\mathbb C$ and then  use algebraic closure to finish the deal

Comment: Okay, good to know that it's not something I ever touched upon, so I'll ignore that fact for now. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be the case, that's why I didn't insist on that at the beginning, and used quote marks around "easy". And you're welcome of course !